# check if file on sdcard specific folder

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-file

I'm trying to make a simple check if the file exist. I saw similar questions here, but they didn't help.
I wrote some code to check if file exist

```
private String checkIfFileExist(String fileName) {
    String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File file = new File(root_sd + "/myfolder");
    if (file != null) {
        File list[] = file.listFiles();
        if (list != null && list.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                if (list[i].getName().equals(fileName)) {
                    return list[i].getName();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I try to check if file does not exist then save some files in this folder.I have problem.for example in my folder i have myimage.png file and my code not working perfect because myimage.png also downloaded and i have two files myimage.png and mypng-1.png
I don't know what is a wrong in my code

Comment: File file = new File(root_sd + "/myfolder/" + fileName);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
String path=<YOUR FOLDER PATH + APPEND FILE NAME>;
File newfile=new File(path);
 if (newfile.exists())
 {
  //Do your task
 }
```

or simply

```
private String checkIfFileExist(String fileName) {
   String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
   String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
   File file = new File(root_sd + "/myfolder/"+filename);
   if (file.exists())
    {
      return file.getName();
    }else
    {
     return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this helps you

```
   File file = new File(root_sd + "/myfolder");
if (file.exists()) {
    File list[] = file.listFiles();
    if (list != null && list.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i].getName().equals(fileName)) {
                return list[i].getName();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, its working for me.

```
  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/myfolder/" + filename);
     if (path.exists()) {
    //do what ever you need to do
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check for file name also.

```
File file = new File(root_sd + "/myfolder/"+filename);
if (file.exists()){
 // write your logic for  file exist here 
}else {
//write your logic for  file does not exist  here 
}
```